# Complexity - how to calculate

Tags: complexity-theory

I know some might asked this before but I will try.

let's say I have a array that I sort in bubble sort

and than (after I finished sorting) I sort it again (by a different comparison ) in order to

achieve my purpose.

in the first time I used : O(n<sup>2</sup>)  .

in the second time I used : O(n<sup>2</sup>)  .

== > I achieved my purpose with complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>)  .

or some thing else (O(n<sup>3</sup>)   or 2*O(n<sup>2</sup>)   or I do not know what)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O(n<sup>2</sup>) + O(n<sup>2</sup>)   = O(n<sup>2</sup>)     in Theory

**First Time:**

> f<sub>1</sub>(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

**Second Time:**

> g<sub>1</sub>(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

**sum:**

> f<sub>1</sub>(n) + g<sub>1</sub>(n)  ⊆  O( n<sup>2</sup>   + n<sup>2</sup>)
>   f<sub>1</sub>(n) + g<sub>1</sub>(n)  ⊆  O(2n<sup>2</sup>)   ⊆  O(n<sup>2</sup>)

**The following properties can be useful:**

[image: fig]

Also, using first rule:

> O( n<sup>2</sup>)   + O(n<sup>2</sup>)    ⊆ O(n<sup>2</sup>)